# Javascript display windows.VARIABLE then it sets

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For example code (`FetchInfo` - custom function):

```
window.FetchInfo.get({ url: 'api/user/5' }).then(function(response) {
    window.USER_INFO = response;
});

function runDisplay() {
    console.log(USER_INFO);   
}
```

How can I run `runDisplay()` function then `USER_INFO` is set and ready?. Can't run function after `window.USER_INFO = response;`. Need something like `addEventListener load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution, working great.

```
window.FetchInfo.get({ url: 'api/user/5' }).then(function(response) {
    window.USER_INFO = response;

    document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('user_info', { detail: { action: USER_INFO } }),
    );
});

function runDisplay() {
    console.log(USER_INFO);   
}

document.addEventListener('user_info', function(event) {
    runDisplay();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition to check window.USER_INFO

```
function request (){
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((data) => {
    if(window.USER_INFO=== undefined){
        window.USER_INFO=data;
    }
    runDisplay(USER_INFO);
    });
}

function runDisplay (test) {
    console.log(test);
}
request();
```

Comment: I need to run function runDisplay() then window.USER_INFO is set - please read it again, wrong answer

Comment: use window.addEventListner('load',runDisplay()); this will run your runDisplay Method when load event occurs. Next part of question please ellaborate

Comment: You don't understand the question at all. Neither the first nor the second part

Comment: Okay. Can you elaborate? Please add more information to question

Comment: Then fetchInfo get all info from API it sets it to window.USER_INFO. And then it sets and its defined I need to run that function. window.addEventListner('load',runDisplay()); - is only loading that function then document ready, but USER_INFO is not ready yet.

Comment: Okay. Thank you :)

Comment: function request (){
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((data) => {
    if(window.adas === undefined){
        window.adas=data;
    }
    runDisplay(window.adas);
    });
}
request();

function runDisplay (test) {
    console.log(test);
}

Comment: This code helped me to call runDisplay method inside the Promise. Please copy and verify code. If this helped you please, take down downvote :)

Comment: My code can't be changed. It has to be the same. And your code does not work as I need.